# Different XTIR results between Excel, Google Spreadsheets, LibreOffice Calc and my algorithm

Tags: excel

I am developing an algorithm to calculate XIRR, and I found some differences between excel and my algorithm, so I decided to compare other software that have the XIRR formula.

I found the following differences

```
 -0.0014968440379778700 Google Sheets
 -0.0014968440379778900 My algorithm
 -0.0014968440379778800 LibreOffice Calc
 -0.0014968425035476700 Excel
```

Apparently Excel "loses" precision after the 8 decimal.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xirr-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d)

> Excel uses an iterative technique for calculating XIRR. Using a
> changing rate (starting with guess), XIRR cycles through the
> calculation until the result is accurate within 0.000001 percent. If
> XIRR can't find a result that works after 100 tries, the #NUM! error
> value is returned...

So, if you want to specify your own criteria for when you want to stop iterating in your own implementation, you can; but the criteria in Excel are hardcoded.

In practice "matching Bloomberg yield exactly for the same cash flows" may be more desirable than "solving for more precise yield".